# How to use nextjs middleware function properly with getServerSideProps function?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to use nextjs middleware function. Here I create middleware file and add this code

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { nextUrl: url, geo } = req

    const country = geo?.country || 'US'

    url.searchParams.set('country', country)

    return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/'
}
```

In Index page-

```
export default function Home(props: any) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <h1 className={styles.title}>
      Welcome to {props.country}
    </h1>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = ({ query }: any) => ({
  props: query,
})
```

Here I am showing country name into `h1` tag from `props.country`. It works perfectly.

But Here we know in `geo` object, middleware gives us-

city,
region,
latitude,
longitude,
country

In middleware function I want to sent full `geo` object and receive from page components to showing all those geo information. How can I do that.

I am trying to sent by this

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { nextUrl: url, geo } = req
    //Here I am try to sent full geo object, not only country as string
    //Please tell me any way to sent object from here to page component.
    url.searchParams.set('country', geo)

    return NextResponse.rewrite(url)
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/'
}
```

From the page component, I want to receive all field such as `city`, `region`, `latitude`, `longitude` and `country`. Please help me and I hope I can clear my question.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an object as the value to `url.searchParams.set` won't work because this value will be serialized in the process.

Instead, you can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn the object into a string. Like so:

```js
url.searchParams.set("geo", JSON.stringify(geo));
```

Then in your component, you use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn it into an object again:

```js
const geo = JSON.parse(props.geo);
```